Configuration R/S of glucose
I can't understand why carbon 2 of D-glucose is in R configuration.

In my opinion, the priority is OH > CH(OH)- > CHO > H since in the 3rd rank, we have an oxygen for CH(OH)- while we only have a ghost carbon for the aldehyde.

Where is my mistake?

Your mistake is, you don't have "ghost" carbon on $\ce{CHO}$ group. The $\ce{C1}$ has double bond with oxygen. Thus it is really $\ce{O-C1(H)-O}$ as you correctly put on your diagram. Therefore, it is a "ghost" oxygen (see the explanation given in the answer below).

I think that you believe that the "ghost" oxygen (O) has an atomic no. of zero, which is not true.
The "ghost" oxygen has the same atomic no. as a normal oxygen.
In sphere 1 of the digraph oxygen has the top priority, hydrogen the lowest and $\ce{C1}$ is tied with $\ce{C3}$. In sphere 2, one has $\ce{C1}${O,(O),H} and $\ce{C3}${O,C,H}. Because (O)>C, $\ce{C1}$>$\ce{C3}$. Thus, priorities on $\ce{C2}$ are O>$\ce{C1}$>$\ce{C3}$>H. Therefore, $\ce{C2}$ has the R-configuration.
PS: You may want to look at this example.


I thought that according to CIP rules, we should only consider the atom with the highest atomic number in each rank: at rank 2, $C_1$ and $C_3$ have an oxygen (atom with the highest atomic number) so we should separate them by looking at rank 3.

You don’t need rank 3! The C1/C3 tie is resolved at rank 2. First, O=(O). Thus, C1{O,O,H} ranks higher than C3{O,C,H}.
